# How to create prefixed dynamic urls in NextJS routes

Tags: next.js

we have following url structure to follow:

```
www.example.com/blogs
www.example.com/products
```

these are working fine, using folder based routing, now the urls which need to be working:

```
www.example.com/blogs-<slug>
www.example.com/product-<slug>
```

we tried catch all option provided by nextjs and handle the views using condition, but only one url is working, since second url is handled by first route.

we need something like

```
pages/product-[product_slug].js
```

how can we achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to use `www.example.com/blogs/<slug>`?

Comment: no, need to be done at root level only

Comment: I think a solution would be to re-route from these URLs to `/[product|blogs]/<slug>` in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Propose solution based on middleware.

```
export default async function middleware(req) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
 
  if (
    pathname.startsWith('/product-') || pathname.startsWith('/blogs-')
  ) {
    const regexp = '(product|blogs)-(.+)'
    const re = new RegExp(regexp, 'g')
    const matches = re.exec(pathname)
    req.nextUrl.pathname += matches[1]+'/'+matches[2]
    return NextResponse.redirect(req.nextUrl)
  }
}
```

This might be improved a bit with middleware matcher instead of checking pathname in code but you should get the gist of it.

You then use the `/product/[slug]` and `blogs/[slug]` route that will match.